# I'm trying to do stuff with inheritance but none of it will work

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance

Im trying to get different variables from loan but none of them ever get to loan.java. My inheritance goes from Loan.Java > BusinessLoan.java > CreateLoan.java. I can get a variable from CreateLoan to display in business but when I set it in business I can't grab it. And I know some of this stuff is stupid but this is my final so some of the stuff was required. Heres my code

Loan.java

```
package Construction;

public class Loan implements LoanConstant{
    public static int loanNumber;
    public static String lastName;
    public static int loanAmount;
    public static int interestRate;
    public static int term;
    public int primeRate;

    public int getLoanNumber() { return loanNumber; }
    public void setLoanNumber(int n) { n = loanNumber; }

    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public void setLastName(String s) { s = lastName; }

    public int getLoanAmount() { return loanAmount; }
    public void setLoanAmount(int n) {
        n = loanAmount; 
        if (loanAmount > MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT)
            loanAmount = MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT;
        }

    public int getTerm() { return term; }
    public void setTerm(int n) { 
        n = term; 
        if (term == 1) {
            term = SHORT_TERM;
        } else if (term == 3) {
            term = MEDIUM_TERM;
        } else if(term == 5) {
            term = LONG_TERM;
        } else
            term = SHORT_TERM;
    }

    public int getInterestRate() { return interestRate; }
    public void setInterestRate(int i) { i = interestRate; }

    public static void displayAll() {
        System.out.println("The Company's Name is " + COMPANY_NAME);
        System.out.println("The loan number is " + loanNumber);
        System.out.println("The last name on the loan is " + lastName);
        System.out.println("The loan amount is " + loanAmount);
        System.out.println("The interest rate on the loan is " + interestRate);
        System.out.println("The term on the account is " + term);
    }
}
```

PersonalLoan.java

```
package Construction;

public class PersonalLoan extends Loan{

    public PersonalLoan(int ln, String last, int la, int term) {
        setLoanNumber(ln);
        setLastName(last);
        setLoanAmount(la);
        setTerm(term);
        interestRate = (int)((primeRate * 0.02) + primeRate);
        setInterestRate(interestRate);
    }
}
```

BusinessLoan.java

```
package Construction;

public class BusinessLoan extends Loan{

    public BusinessLoan(int ln, String last, int la, int term) {
        setLoanNumber(ln);
        setLastName(last);
        setLoanAmount(la);
        setTerm(term);
        interestRate = (int)((primeRate * 0.01) + primeRate);
        setInterestRate(interestRate);
    }

}
```

CreateLoan.java

```
package Construction;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class CreateLoan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int primeRate;
        String type;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Loan[] loans = new Loan[5];
        System.out.println("Please enter the prime interest rate");
        primeRate = input.nextInt();
        primeRate = primeRate/100;
        input.nextLine();

        for(x = 0; x < 6; ++x) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a loan type. Choose either Business or Personal. If you don't type it like that you'll get an error.");
            type = input.nextLine();
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Business")) {
                System.out.println("What is the account number on the loan?");
                int ln = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("What is the last name on the account?");
                String last = input.nextLine();
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("What is the loan amount? If you put more then 100k it'll only accept up to 100k");
                int la = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("What is the term on the account? If you enter something other then 1, 3, or 5 it will default to a short term.");
                int term = input.nextInt();
                loans[x] = new BusinessLoan(ln, last, la, term);
                System.out.println("The Company's Name is " + Loan.COMPANY_NAME);
                System.out.println("The loan number is " + loans[x].getLoanNumber());
                System.out.println("The last name on the loan is " + loans[x].getLastName());
                System.out.println("The loan amount is " + loans[x].getLoanAmount());
                System.out.println("The interest rate on the loan is " + loans[x].getInterestRate());
                System.out.println("The term on the account is " + loans[x].getTerm());
            }
            else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Personal")) {
                System.out.println("What is the account number on the loan?");
                int ln = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("What is the last name on the account?");
                String last = input.nextLine();
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("What is the loan amount? If you put more then 100k it'll only accept up to 100k");
                int la = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("What is the term on the account? If you enter something other then 1, 3, or 5 it will default to a short term.");
                int term = input.nextInt();
                loans[x] = new PersonalLoan(ln, last, la, term);
                System.out.println("The Company's Name is " + Loan.COMPANY_NAME);
                System.out.println("The loan number is " + loans[x].getLoanNumber());
                System.out.println("The last name on the loan is " + loans[x].getLastName());
                System.out.println("The loan amount is " + loans[x].getLoanAmount());
                System.out.println("The interest rate on the loan is " + loans[x].getInterestRate());
                System.out.println("The term on the account is " + loans[x].getTerm());
            } else {
                System.out.println("You've entered an invalid type. Please restart and try again.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LoanConstants.java

```
package Construction;

public interface LoanConstant {
    public final static int SHORT_TERM = 1;
    public final static int MEDIUM_TERM = 3;
    public final static int LONG_TERM = 5;
    public final static String COMPANY_NAME = "Sanchez Construction";
    public final static int MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT = 100000;
}
```

Comment: Don't make your instance fields `static`!

Comment: Like my variables in Loan? I just did that and I still get 0's for everything but last name which is null and term which is 1.

Comment: I don't see a `theVariable` in your code.  So instead of saying that your program never changes "the variable", you might want to tell us what variable you're talking about.  There is a lot of code here, and we're not willing to go through that much code with no idea what we're supposed to look for.

Comment: Sorry. I meant any of the variables in loan. I edited it

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `Loan` fields being static (remove the static). You should also update your setters.

```
public void setLoanNumber(int n) { n = loanNumber; }
public void setLastName(String s) { s = lastName; }
```

You are assigning the value to the passed in variable (not the field). Should be

```
public void setLoanNumber(int n) { loanNumber = n; }
public void setLastName(String s) { lastName = s; }
```

and

```
public void setTerm(int n) { 
    // n = term; 
    if (n == 1) {
        term = SHORT_TERM;
    } else if (n == 3) {
        term = MEDIUM_TERM;
    } else if (n == 5) {
        term = LONG_TERM;
    } else
        term = SHORT_TERM;
}

public void setInterestRate(int i) { interestRate = i; }
```